# How to run MaxQuant in command line mode?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

MaxQuant is a software package for mass spectroscopy and proteomics. There is a windows version and a linux version. To run on linux you have to use a program that is called `mono`. I think, it is developed by Microsoft, which I find quite nice from them. I installed mono on Linux and started MaxQuant.

```
mono MaxQuant.exe
```

The [documentation](http://www.coxdocs.org/doku.php?id=maxquant:common:download_and_installation) claims it is for running MaxQuant in commandline mode, though a GUI is started anyway. How can I start the program in commandline mode to perform batch analysis? I think, there is not enough information given on the web-page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give

```
mono MaxQuantCmd.exe [OPTIONS]
```

a try.

[University of Oslo](https://www.uio.no/english/services/it/research/hpc/abel/help/software/maxquant.html) description of how to use the tool in their infrastructure.

Comment: Kohl, the link is broken. Could you update it please?

Answer (score 0):

You can now install MaxQuant simply with Conda:

```
conda install -c bioconda maxquant
```

and to run MaxQuant type:

```
maxquant mqpar.xml
```

[Reference](https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/maxquant/README.html)